# Follow cursor on scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll

On my page I have new comment box's that stack on top each other every couple of seconds. is their a way to follow the comment box I click on. currently if i click it that box gets pushed off the screen when the other box's load on top and have to scroll down manually to it. I would like to auto follow that box I click on... Focus?

Comment: were any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scrolltop function in jQuery.

```
//Everytime, you add a comment, scroll the page to the element
$('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#clickedComment").offset().top
}, 500);
```

[Here's a complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wssj/) but you will see that there is a logic problem. It's not possible to scroll up when you have many comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor:

```
<div id="aDiv"></div>
```

then

```
 location.href = "#";
 location.href = "#aDiv";
```

Or you can use jquery scrollTop: `scrollTop: $(this).offset().top`

Or you can use javascript `scrollTo`: `window.scrollTo(elementPos,0)`

Answer (score 0):

So, to set the scroll, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop

I would implement this 2 ways

An observer pattern with the boxes, that knows when new boxes are added, which checks a flag. The flag itself is set true when there is focus on any comment box, and false when there is not.

Scrolltop can be jarring in a UI, but perhaps you can figure out a way to animate it, I won't spoon feed you further.

Check out Addy Osmanis book if you need help with design patterns!

http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/